# BIOS UEFI mode settings

Tags: debian, system-installation, uefi, bios

I want reinstall Debian11 from LiveUSB, in UEFI mode: should I disable in BIOS these two options: "Secure Boot: disabled" and "Load Legacy Option Rom: disabled", apart from set BIOS UEFI mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian 11 includes provisions for Secure Boot, but if you plan to use third-party kernel modules (DKMS packages or otherwise), or build your own kernels, then disabling Secure Boot makes things easier.

It's possible to install the OS with Secure Boot disabled, then later ensure all the necessary pieces to support it are in place, and enable it if you wish.

`Load Legacy Option ROM` is a tricky one. If you have an add-on GPU/display card, and it does not have a UEFI driver built into its video BIOS, then your display will be black until the kernel starts up and loads a suitable framebuffer display driver that is capable of initializing the card, unless you enable loading legacy option ROMs (and maybe also the legacy BIOS Compatibility Support Module). Also, if you have a storage controller that supplies its own legacy-only BIOS extension (e.g. a hardware RAID card), and you want to boot from it, then you would have to enable loading the legacy option ROM.

But if you have no add-on GPUs or storage controllers, or your add-on GPU includes a UEFI GOP driver in its VideoBIOS, then you can disable loading of legacy option ROMs.

Normally I would expect a UEFI firmware to include support for any GPU and storage that is integrated into the system board. But if your hardware is from very early PC-UEFI era (say, from years 2011-2012), its UEFI implementation might be hastily done and/or have bugs. Some very early UEFI implementations were really only usable in legacy-compatibility mode.